# Selecting list of objects where property of a specific type in entityframework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Currently struggling to filter a list of objects (called Field) where these objects have an inherited property, this property is called **FieldReference**. This is an abstract class and all Field objects have this property but it can be of different types such as;

```
DebtorFieldReference
```

What we're trying to do is query all fields where the Property is of the type DebtorFieldReference and further more we also want to then filter on a value in this DebtorFieldReference object called DebtorId.

We tried the following snippet but EF doesnt allow us to cast, we also tried to query on GetType without success.

```
var results = FieldProvider.Get(f => f.FieldOwnerTypeId == (byte)Enum.FieldReferenceType.Debtor && ((DebtorFieldReference)f.FieldReference).DebtorId == message.Reference);
```

I've in the past done this with NHibernate without any problems, please tell me i'm just doing something wrong and EF isn't hugely limited in this way :-(

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

After some trial and error I actually got it working, not entirely sure why this would work but the Cast would not but here is the line that did it;

```
var results = FieldProvider.Get(f => (f.FieldReference as DebtorFieldReference).DebtorId == message.Reference);
```

So in other words, use 'as' and not cast, maybe cast and as behave differently when it concerns null values.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the performance of the generated SQL ?

Comment: What would you like me to elaborate on exactly? It's a relatively complex database design so the actual query (which is more complex then what I posted here) is rather ugly as there are some unions in play (effectively the Field object is an abstract as well and we have IntField, StringField etc.) Other than that it's not that bad, it makes a join towards the table which holds the DebtorFieldReference information, and checks if the DebtorId in this table has the required value.

Comment: On second look, the query that is generated is actually really ugly, far worst then the SQL I'd normally get out of NHibernate, dispite only selecting DebtorFieldReference it still unions the other types in the inheritance tree..... Which is completely pointless. Maybe its because I don't have an != null the filter at this point.